# Nilpotent elements of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

**I have a unital commutative ring $A$. And we know that an element $a \in A$ is said to be nilpotent if $a^n=0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove the following assertions:**

> **a) $A$ does not contain nonzero nilpotent elements if and only if zero is the unique element in $A$ whose square is zero.**

Here, what've done is:

$\Rightarrow$: Trivial. We know $ \nexists\ 0\neq a \in A $ such that $a^n=0$ fore some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, in special for n=2.

$\Leftarrow$: $0$ is the unique element in $A$ whose square is $0$. Then   $ \exists\ 0\neq a \in A $ such that $a^n=0$ fore some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

We know that if $a \neq 0$, $a\in A$, then $a^2\neq 0$. Suppose $a^n=0$ with $a\neq 0$

Notice that $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so because of the algorithm division we can write $n$ as $n=n_1\cdot 2+r$ where $r<2$ then, $r=1$ or $r=0$. In both cases we can write
$0= a^n=a^{2n_1+r}=a^{2n_1}a^r=(a^{n_1})^2a^r$

where $a^r\neq 0$ (because if $r=1$, then $a^r=a$, if $r=0$ then $a^0=1_A$ so $a^{n_1}=0$ and we can write $n_1$ as: $n_1=n_2\cdot2+r_1$ where $r_1<2$ then, $r_1=1$ or $r_1=0$ and continue as before.
Whe now that it will have a finite number of steps because $n_k<n_{k-1}<\ldots<n_2<n_1<n$ for some $k$ that:

$n_k=2\cdot 1+r_k$ with $r_k<2$

Then $0= a^n_k=a^{2\cdot1+r_k}=a^{2}a^{r_k}$ and we know $a^{r_k}\neq 0$ so $a^2=0$ CONTRADICTION with the hipothesis. So $a=0$ if $a^n=0$, $a\in A$
QED.

It is well proved? I don't know that if I do the "continue as before" is ok with the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a problem with your proof : from the fact that $a^{2n_1}\cdot a =0$ you deduce $a^{2n_1}=0$, but your ring is not integral, so this is not obvious (even though in the end it is true because the whole point is that $a$ is not nilpotent).

Comment: Hint : if for instance $a^4 = 0$, you can deduce as you did that $a^2 = 0$. But if $a^3 = 0$, then $a^4 = a^3a = 0$.

Comment: Perhaps, the best way to make the proof work would be picking the smallest positive natural number $m$ such that there exists $a\ne 0$ satisfying $a^m=0$, and observe that it can be neither $1$ nor $2$.

Comment: Your "Then $\;0=a_k^n=...\;$" part seems to be wrong as you seem to be assuming $\;A\;$ has no zero divisors as you say $\;a^2a^{r_k}=0\implies a^2=0\;$ since we know $\;a^{r_k}\neq0\;$

Comment: That's true, then my proof it's wrong because i've assumed that my ring is integral (and is not). But I don't know how to fix it. Even I don't understand the way Sassatelli says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you arrive at $0=a^2a^{r_k}$, with $a^{r_k}\ne0$, you cannot conclude $a^2=0$.

---

Suppose $a^n=0$ and $b=a^{n-1}\ne0$, for $n>1$. Then
$$
b^2=(a^{n-1})^2=a^{2n-2}=a^na^{n-2}=0
$$
Therefore…

Answer (score 3):

I think the nontrivial part can be more or less as you did but with the following fixing: suppose $\;0\neq a\in A\;$ is such that $\;a^{2n+1}=0\;$ and this is the lowest possible exponent (the nilpotency degree or something), but then

$$\left(a^{n+1}\right)^2=a^{2n+1}a=0\cdot a=0\implies a^{n+1}=0$$

and we get contradiction to nilpotency degree.